# Using main thread to synchronize / lock vars

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, locking

I'm writing a program which will have many dynamically generated async tasks taking place. To read / write global vars I've been employing a wait lock in a while loop (see 1 below). I feel like this might not be efficient, so I was thinking I could instead manipulate global vars in the main thread (see 2 below). Will this actually be more efficient?

**1. Wait Lock Example**

```
var writeLock = false
var someVar = 0

func someFunc() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {   
                while (self.writeLock) { } // Wait for lock
                self.writeLock = true // Lock
                self.someVar += 1  // Manipulate var
                self.writeLock = false // Unlock
        }
}
```

**2. Thread Lock Example**

```
var someVar = 0

func someFunc() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {   
                // Access main queue
                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                        self.someVar += 1  // Manipulate var
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use DispatchGroup instead ?

Comment: Oh that sounds cool

Comment: You can just create one task and add in the group and that will fulfill your writelock task

Comment: You should use a private serial dispatch queue and dispatch updates to the properties synchronously on that queue

Comment: @ShubhamMishra I don't see how a dispatch group will guard a critical section.

Comment: I mean when you have two task then after completion of one task then only you can move on another task. Till the completion of one task second task is locked.

Comment: See this project and go through it :- https://github.com/shubham321mishra/CustomAlert

Comment: I don't know Swift, but in your first example, what prevents some other thread from setting `writelock` to `true` again immediately after the `// Wait for lock` line executes, but before the `// Lock` line executes?

Comment: Use dispatch `sync` not `async` and if you could potentially even use mutex locks.